# Yolo and Clip to find top 3 similar images

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo, openai-clip

```
import os
import clip
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
from typing import List, Dict
import concurrent.futures
import pickle
import time

def tokenize_text(text: List[str], tokenizer):
    """
    Tokenize the input text using the CLIP tokenizer.

    Parameters:
        text (List[str]): List of input texts to be tokenized.
        tokenizer (clip.simple_tokenizer.SimpleTokenizer): The CLIP tokenizer.

    Returns:
        List of tokenized texts.
    """
    return [tokenizer.encode(t) for t in text]

def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    """
    Calculate the cosine similarity between two vectors.

    Parameters:
        a (numpy.ndarray): The first vector.
        b (numpy.ndarray): The second vector.

    Returns:
        float: The cosine similarity between the two vectors.
    """
    return np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))

def process_image(image_path, entity, tokenizer, preprocess, model):
    """
    Process a single image and calculate the similarity score with a given entity.

    Parameters:
        image_path (str): The file path of the image to be processed.
        entity (str): The entity to compare the image with.
        tokenizer (clip.simple_tokenizer.SimpleTokenizer): The CLIP tokenizer.
        preprocess (Callable): Image preprocessing function from the CLIP model.
        model (clip.model.CLIP): The CLIP model.

    Returns:
        Tuple: The image path and the similarity score between the image and entity.
    """
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        text = tokenize_text([entity], tokenizer)
        image_input = preprocess(image).unsqueeze(0)
        image_features = model.encode_image(image_input).detach().numpy()
        text_features = model.encode_text(text).detach().numpy()
        similarity = cosine_similarity(image_features, text_features)
        return image_path, similarity

def compute_embeddings(all_images_folder, model, tokenizer, preprocess):
    """
    Pre-compute embeddings for all images and cache them for faster retrieval.

    Parameters:
        all_images_folder (str): The folder containing all images.
        model (clip.model.CLIP): The CLIP model.
        tokenizer (clip.simple_tokenizer.SimpleTokenizer): The CLIP tokenizer.
        preprocess (Callable): Image preprocessing function from the CLIP model.
    """
    image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(all_images_folder) if file.endswith(".jpg")]

    embeddings = {}
    for image_file in tqdm(image_files, desc="Computing Embeddings"):
        image_path = os.path.join(all_images_folder, image_file)
        with Image.open(image_path) as image:
            image_input = preprocess(image).unsqueeze(0)
            image_features = model.encode_image(image_input).detach().numpy()
            embeddings[image_file] = image_features

    with open('embeddings_cache.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(embeddings, f)

def find_closest_matches(tagged_images_folder: str, all_images_folder: str):
    """
    Find the top 3 similar images for each entity and save them in respective folders.

    Parameters:
        tagged_images_folder (str): The folder containing tagged images for each entity.
        all_images_folder (str): The folder containing all images.

    Notes:
        This function uses the CLIP model for image and text embeddings and the cosine similarity metric
        to find the top 3 most similar images for each entity.
    """
    model, preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", jit=False)
    tokenizer = clip.simple_tokenizer.SimpleTokenizer()

    # Check if embeddings are cached
    if os.path.exists('embeddings_cache.pkl'):
        with open('embeddings_cache.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            embeddings = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        compute_embeddings(all_images_folder, model, tokenizer, preprocess)
        with open('embeddings_cache.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            embeddings = pickle.load(f)

    entity_folders = [folder for folder in os.listdir(tagged_images_folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tagged_images_folder, folder))]

    for entity_folder in entity_folders:
        entity_images_folder = os.path.join(tagged_images_folder, entity_folder)
        entity_cropped_folder = os.path.join(all_images_folder, "results", entity_folder)
        os.makedirs(entity_cropped_folder, exist_ok=True)

        image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(entity_images_folder) if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png"))]

        # Initialize a dictionary to store similarity scores for each entity
        entity_similarities = {}

        # Process images and calculate similarity for each entity
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future_to_path = {executor.submit(process_image, os.path.join(entity_images_folder, file), os.path.splitext(file)[0], tokenizer, preprocess, model): file for file in image_files}
            for future in tqdm(concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_path), total=len(future_to_path), desc=f"Processing {entity_folder}"):
                img_path, similarity = future.result()
                entity = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_path))[0]

                # Add similarity score to the dictionary
                if entity not in entity_similarities:
                    entity_similarities[entity] = []
                entity_similarities[entity].append((img_path, similarity))

        # Save the top 3 similar images for each entity in its respective folder
        for entity, similarities in entity_similarities.items():
            # Sort similarities for the current entity
            similarities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

            # Create a folder for the current entity if it doesn't exist
            entity_output_folder = os.path.join(entity_cropped_folder, entity)
            os.makedirs(entity_output_folder, exist_ok=True)

            # Save the main image in the entity folder
            main_image_path = os.path.join(entity_output_folder, "main_image.jpg")
            main_image = Image.open(similarities[0][0])
            main_image.save(main_image_path)

            # Create a subfolder for similar images
            similar_images_folder = os.path.join(entity_output_folder, "similar_images")
            os.makedirs(similar_images_folder, exist_ok=True)

            # Save the top 3 similar images (cropped out) in the similar_images subfolder
            for i, (img_path, _) in enumerate(similarities[:3]):
                similar_img = Image.open(img_path)
                similar_img.save(os.path.join(similar_images_folder, f"top{i+1}-{os.path.basename(img_path)}"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tagged_images_folder = r"c:\Users\amrit\Aryan\CS\python\Adobe hack-a-thon\Round 2 prep\Aithon\adobe_aithon_alpha\question1\All_Images"
    all_images_folder = r"c:\Users\amrit\Aryan\CS\python\Adobe hack-a-thon\Round 2 prep\Aithon\adobe_aithon_alpha\question1\boxed_images"

    start_time = time.time()
    find_closest_matches(tagged_images_folder, all_images_folder)
    end_time = time.time()

    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Total time taken: {total_time:.2f} seconds")
```

The code should be outputing images with this file structure

boxed_images/results/entity_folder/main_image.jpg and boxed_images/results/entity_folder/similar_images/topX-image_name.jpg for each entity.

I am trying to optimize the code and make it fast but as of now I just want the code to work

These are the two images from where i got the questions

[image]

[image]